# Differences between android studio layouts

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to android studio and I am having trouble selecting a layout. There are 5 different layouts. I am using constraint layout because it's the default. Some of my friends said that it's hard to use. What is the main difference between those layouts?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the different layouts?

Comment: I suggest you create a project with different activites and try out the different layouts with a couple of views in each one. You will be able to understand the differences and get an ide of when to use each one.

Comment: I hope this tutorial can help you. - https://www.codejourney.net/2017/04/android-layout-types/

Comment: There's more than 5-  you can create your own if you want to.  Pick the one that has the options you need and the cheapest cost for layout and measure passes.  Constraint is new and powerful, but it can be somewhat slow and has a lot of options you need to learn to use it well.  Linear and Relative are the two that are oldest and most commonly used.  You'll likely use a mix of all of them over time, different situations call for different solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've used layout systems in web development like bootstrap or some grid system, you'll find it easy to understand. At first Constraint Layout may look scary and not easy to understand but it really adds a lot of power in positioning the views in responsive manner.

> **Constraints overview**
>
> To define a view's position in ConstraintLayout, you must add at least
>   one horizontal and one vertical constraint for the view. Each
>   constraint represents a connection or alignment to another view, the
>   parent layout, or an invisible guideline. Each constraint defines the
>   view's position along either the vertical or horizontal axis; so each
>   view must have a minimum of one constraint for each axis, but often
>   more are necessary. When you drop a view into the Layout Editor, it
>   stays where you leave it even if it has no constraints. However, this
>   is only to make editing easier; if a view has no constraints when you
>   run your layout on a device, it is drawn at position [0,0] (the
>   top-left corner).

Try this Codelab :

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/constraint-layout/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0

Some resources:

https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout#constraints-overview

https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P9Zstbk0lPw

I personally use Coordinator and Relative Layout. You can try them out if you like. I'd suggest that you must begin with these two but definitely try out other layouts in say a example project and learn about them.

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Constructing-View-Layouts

Answer (score 1):

I've found a [very clear answer](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-differences-in-ConstraintLayout-LinearLayout-CoordinatorLayout-RelativeLayout-and-FrameLayout-in-Android-Studio):

> **FrameLayout** is designed to hold one child object. For example, have Recycler View inside a FrameLayout but nothing else.
>
> **CoordinatorLayout** is an improved version of FrameLayout. Mostly used
>   for improving the performance of the child object. For example, let’s
>   say we have a ListView and I want to change the scrolling behavior
>   when a user interaction happen. I can use CoordinatorLayout in this to
>   make ListView behave as I want.
>
> **LinearLayout** is designed to align child objects in one direction i.e
>   horizontally or vertically. For example, If I have a TextView,
>   ImageView, and EditText and I want them to in a line, so I can use
>   LinearLayout with a horizontal orientation to do this.
>
> **RelativeLayout** is a bit more complex than above two but has a lot more
>   capability. RelativeLayout is designed to align the child object
>   relative to parent or some other child object position. For example,
>   nowadays we usually have a button at the end of the screen on the
>   right side, the ways this is done we create a RelativeLayout as the
>   parent and then a button inside it with parameters alignParentBotton
>   and alignParentRight = True.
>
> **ConstraintLayout** is an updated version of RelativeLayout i.e providing
>   a lot more parameters than RelativeLayout and improved functionality.